# Script loaded from content delivery network with no integrity check

Tags: javascript, security, materialize, cdn, code-analysis

Am running code quality analysis using [LGTM](https://lgtm.com/) tool on my flask app which uses Material CSS for its javascript. To access the javascript one should use(According to Documentation):
 `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script`
,this however results in a security flaw described as **Script loaded from content delivery network with no integrity check.**

Question:
Do you know any cdn network in which material css has intergrity code? e.g for jquery is: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous">`